# How to dynamically wrap root layout in a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a scroll view to all the layouts that I have. But dynamically. Because the app will run in different screen sizes, and when I will get a screen size smaller than a specific size, then I want to show the layout in a scroll view.

So I made this method, it will be called on the check that the screen is small. I will pass my activity and I want to change the root layout to scroll view or just add a ScrollView as the root layout. So if the root layout is a LinearLayout, then I want to put that layout in the ScrollView. And I have not named all the layouts, meaning that I didn't give an ID to the layout, so I cannot use `findViewById`.

```
public static void SetActivityRoot(Activity c) {
    View v = c.getWindow().getDecorView();
    // View v = v.getRootView();

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(c);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    sv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v);

    sv.addView((View) v);
    ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).addView(sv);
}
```

It's giving me an error saying that "you cannot remove view from null" etc. Or that "you cannot add view to layout as it already has parent view".  How can I make this work?

Comment: why you are doing this, scroll view knows where I need to show scroll or not, if screen size is larger than content scrollview will not show up, it'll show only when content is larger than screen size

Comment: you can use scrollview in your xml file ,it will detect if the content is not larger than its size then wouldn't show scrollbar.

Comment: Actually the app has more than 46 layouts. And we will be adding more. And i don't want to go to each layout and add scroll view. So i thought i could do this dynamically. If i will not be able to do this, then the last resort will be to add them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem.

```
public static void SetActivityRoot(Activity c) {
    View v = ((ViewGroup)c.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(c);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    sv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeAllViews();

    sv.addView((View) v);
    c.addContentView(sv, lp);
}
```